# G1GC Old Gen committed heap keeps growing, used is constant - leads to Eden starvation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, garbage-collection, openshift-origin, g1gc

The G1GC old generation committed heap goes up over time (about 5 to 6 days on production) but the old generation used heap does not.  The Eden and survivor heap is forced to decrease to the minimum (5% of the total heap) and so garbage collection because more and more frequent.  The application caches one big object graph right at the beginning and then has other time/use limited caching throughout its run lifetime.  It has a fairly high object creation rate but does not promote much of that to the old generation apart from the cached objects.

I have run the GC log through gceasy.io and you can see the above behaviour of the memory:
 https://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMjAvMDUvMTEvLS1nY2xvZy50YXIuZ3otLTExLTMwLTE5&channel=WEB.

gclog:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=176X-Lku4D3DGCCdTiB0_z545N8n0tfKc

Grafana memory metrics for this run https://snapshot.raintank.io/dashboard/snapshot/k6g3ljG7cQUEJM7jA4c5tBK1dsUnzabd

Heap dump at end of run (load had been removed for about an hour, this is a 500M gz file): https://drive.google.com/open?id=14ghzIVnpelInSyQBhCwUwM5VkuOjX13-

We do not seem to have high humongous object creation. The server has 12G of RAM and the heap has 6G.

The jvm:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

The jvm flags:

```
-XX:CICompilerCount=4
-XX:ConcGCThreads=2
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=2097152
-XX:GCLogFileSize=104857600
-XX:InitialHeapSize=6442450944
-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50.000000
-XX:+ManagementServer
-XX:MarkStackSize=4194304
-XX:MaxHeapSize=6442450944
-XX:MaxNewSize=3865051136
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50.000000
-XX:MinHeapDeltaBytes=2097152
-XX:MinRAMPercentage=50.000000
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10
-XX:+PrintGC
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
```

We run on openshift with CentOS: CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)

Kernel: 3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64

Comment: Have you tried to take a heap dump and analyze early in the run, and then after a few days, and compare?

Comment: I have tried that and see nothing special, in particular the actual used heap is always much much lower than the committed heap.  I have a heap dump for the end of this run and it shows 1.3G total heap usage and yet the old generation has committed close to 6G (I will upload a link).  Hence the eden is starved.  I have uploaded a grafana metrics link to show memory usage similar to what gceasy shows.

Comment: @TomDearman I got the same problem (commited ~ 2 * used), did you find what was the root cause ?
When I have a small eden+survivor committed space, a big part of the cpu usage will be used by the gc and the whole application will be slowed down even if I have enough memory

Answer (score 1):

From your GC log, below is how it looks from GCViewer

The GC Log show that Ref Proc is the bottle neck of High GC Time
So suggest try -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled to see if it can help

> ```
>   [Ref Proc: 151.3 ms]
>   [Ref Proc: 147.2 ms]
>   [Ref Proc: 146.6 ms]
>   [Ref Proc: 183.0 ms]
>   [Ref Proc: 156.4 ms]
>   [Ref Proc: 152.7 ms]
>   [Ref Proc: 143.7 ms]
>   [Ref Proc: 137.8 ms]
>   [Ref Proc: 194.8 ms]
>   [Ref Proc: 153.3 ms]
>   [Ref Proc: 153.6 ms]
> ```

There are some other several things could have a try to improve:

1. Turn on -XX:PrintReferenceGC to get more detail time spend on Ref Proc
2. Reduce -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent(default is 45) gradually to see if Mixed GC could happen earlier and help on the behavior
3. Increase -XX:G1NewSizePercent to avoid the Young Generation to reduce too small

Hope can help on it

[image: GC Viewer UI]

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is normal that `committed` memory value is higher than `used`.  Committed starts with `-Xms` and can go up to `-Xmx`, but `committed` is *not* `resident`. `Resident` here means *in RAM*, while `used = resident + swapped pages`. So `used` can fluctuate a lot, while `committed` not that much, at least, this is how I understand this.

A GC starts with the value of `-Xms` as the initial committed memory and will slowly grow (up to `-Xmx` of course). And now that I have made this intro, I really don't think this makes any sense to your application. Let me explain.

As far as I can see from the logs that you provided, everything is pretty much expected (and normal). `G1` has a default value for `MaxGCPauseMillis = 200ms` which indicates how much your application is allowed to be stopped (in the happy path scenario). According to this value, `G1` makes proper decisions to re-size your regions. According to your logs, the `Eden` space of around `270MB` (on average) is collected in up to `0.2s`. Just a random example from your logs:

```
[Eden: 280.0M ....
Times: user=0.49 sys=0.00, real=0.18 secs
2020-05-04T02:43:01.742+0000: 315128.451: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.1740299 secs]
```

So this is exactly what you asked for, indirectly. To me, your application is perfectly fine, those `GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause)` take as much as you have configured. And btw, call yourself lucky? but in that entire log file there is not a single `Full GC` that I can spot (apart from the one when you take the heap dump).